# using @Autowired with static variable

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I try to run the following and get NullPointerException in main function. I don't know why this @Autowired method doesn't initialize surveyDao variable.
Below is related code:

```
@ContextConfiguration( locations = {"test-context.xml"} )
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)

@Transactional
public class MyTest {    


protected static SurveyDao surveyDao;


@Autowired
public void setSurveyDao(SurveyDao surveyDAO){
    MyTest.surveyDao = surveyDAO;
}


public static void main(String args[]) {
    CollectSurvey survey = surveyDao.load("form");
}
```

}

Content of test-context.xml is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <context:annotation-config/>


<!--     <bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="org.openforis.collect.context.ApplicationContextAwareImpl" /> -->

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="file:${user.dir}/dev.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="${collect.devdb.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${collect.devdb.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${collect.devdb.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="surveyDao" class="org.openforis.collect.persistence.SurveyDao" init-method="init">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dynamicTableDao" class="org.openforis.collect.persistence.DynamicTableDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what are you trying to accomplish I can only tell it's not a typical usage for spring framework. Maybe if you write what's your intention it would be possible to come up with a better advice.

Your annotations are not processed at all when you run the main method. No context is built so your `test-context.xml` is ignored. If you want to build context from the main method try:

```
FileSystemXmlApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("test-context.xml");
```

and define MyTest as a bean to see injection of surveyDao.

Comment: I added context initialization in main() and defined MyTest as a bean `<bean id="myTest" class="collcomm.main.MyTest" init-method="init" />`, but surveyDao is still null

Comment: It should work if annotations are being processed and bean is created. You check it for null after context is done initializing?

Comment: Well, I did this: `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("test-context.xml");  
  System.out.println(surveyDao==null);`
and now when I added `surveyDao = (SurveyDao)context.getBean("surveyDao");` before println I have correctly initialized surveyDao

Comment: Okay. That's because you used `default-lazy-init="true"` which I missed at first. Spring preinstantiates singletons by default without this.